# Hudi with Spark perform very slow when trying to write data into filesystem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-hudi

I'm trying Apache Hudi with Spark by a very simple demo:

```
with SparkSession.builder.appName(f"Hudi Test").getOrCreate() as spark:
    df = spark.read.option('mergeSchema', 'true').parquet('s3://an/existing/directory/')
    hudi_options = {
            'hoodie.table.name': 'users_activity',
            'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'users_activity_id',
            'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'users_activity_id',
            'hoodie.datasource.write.table.name': 'users_activity_result',
            'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
            'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'users_activity_create_date',
        }
    df.write.format('hudi').options(**hudi_options).mode('append').save('s3://htm-hawk-data-lake-test/flink_test/copy/users_activity/')
```

There are about 10 parquet files in the directory; their total size is 1GB, about 6 million records. But Hudi takes a very long time to write, and it failed with `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 1409413 tasks (1024.0 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)` after 2 hours.

I have checked the Spark History Server, and it shows as below:
[image: spark ui]
Seems it's collecting all records in parquet files to driver and serializing them. Is it working right? How can I improve its writing performance?

Comment: turn off mergeSchema and see if that helps. any form of schema inference forces the planning stage to look at all the source files.

Comment: @stevel Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hudi seems to write the data without any problem, but it fails the indexing step which tries to collect a list of pairs (`partition path`, `file id`).

You are using the field `users_activity_id` as a partition key and Hudi key, if the cardinality of this field is high, you will have a lot of partitions and then a very long list of pairs (partition, file_id), especially if this field is Hudi key which is supposed to be unique (6M records = 6M partitions)